# JSHint complaining object is not defined when it is defined in external file

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following object in file **remover.js**:

```
'use strict';

(function( remover, $, undefined ) {
  // ...
  // Object's definition
  // ...
}( window.remover = window.remover || {}, jQuery ));
```

This is used on the external file **main.js**:

```
'use strict';

remover.doSomething();
```

The code is working but JSHint throws the following problem:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

app/scripts/stuff/main.js
  line 3  col 1  'remover' is not defined.

✖ 1 problem
```

How to remove this warning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options, one is getting ride of *all* the *undefined* warnings which is bad for your debugging and another one is solving specifically the problem with global entities.

1. Disable var undefined warnings *(bad!)*

   Just disable the warning on the **main.js** file with the [`undef`](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#undef) option

   ```
   'use strict';
   /*jshint undef:false */
   ```
2. Tell JSHint which are the external libraries *(good!)*

   Mention every variable as *global*

   ```
   'use strict';
   /*global remover */
   ```

Now running `grunt jshint` should output:

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

✔ No problems
```

There is more information at the section *Directives* in the [JSHint Documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/).